# changing navigation label name in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to change the navigation of the name in my rails admin dashboard.

This is what I have under my `rails_admin.rb` file

```
  config.model 'Product' do
  list do
    field :id
    field :design_code
    field :brand
    field :is_hidden
    field :filename
end
```

Where am I suppose to change the name of navigations labels?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the navigation label of the `Product` model, or do you want to change the labels of the fields? See the wiki: [Models](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Models) and [Fields](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields]).

Comment: @zwippie I want to rename `Brands` to Company.

Please check the [image](http://i.imgur.com/Me65xw7.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic label configuration for rails admin:

```
config.model 'Product' do
  label 'Item' # Change the label of this model class
  field :id
  field :design_code
  field :brand do
    label 'Company' # Change the label of this field
  end
  field :is_hidden
  field :filename
end
```

See the [rails_admin wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki) for more info.

Comment: `Item` is the label to use instead of `Product`. Please read the rails_admin wiki for more information.

Comment: Well I'm not getting your point either. You want to *change the navigation of the name*?!? That makes no sense to me. I am guessing now that you want to change the text of the link that will lead to the product admin page, and that is what the example is about. And again: please dive into the wiki and **read it** to understand how rails_admin works.

Comment: Then change the `label` of your `Brand` model to `Company`. Did you even read my answer or the wiki?...

Comment: Thanks. You save my day